# Hiding triangles in a triangle strip? (Hiding parts of a model programmatically)

Tags: swift, osx-yosemite, scenekit

I have a KUKA robot model in DAE format converted from STEP. The model is segmented by material (just a flat color) into children of the root node. For example, all the parts considered the robotic arm are included together as a single geometry object and a green material is applied. The underlying elements are one large triangle strip.

I need to separate all the parts of the robot so that I can animate them correctly. There are visual gaps between most of the parts that I plan to separate. My first thought was to look for gaps in the triangle strip, but I don't know how to tell where gaps are located. (Corollary: how can a triangle strip have gaps?)

Second thought was to select ranges of elements to render (binary search style I suppose, manually adjusting the numbers or using an on-screen control.) This would be most useful in the places where the geometry is visually adjacent, but parts need separating.

Question 1: is there a method to determining where gaps exist in the triangle strip?

Question 2: does there exist an API for selecting a subset of elements to render? It would certainly be possible to write this, but looks like lots of work (choosing elements, related sources, texture mapping would probably be right out...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While mnuages' answer provides a suitable answer to the title (actually 'hiding' parts of a geometry), I realized that this would be insufficient because I'd want to programmatically serialize the remaining geometry as a node in the scene.

To answer my "Question 2", I wrote additions to SceneKit classes that would let me generate new SCNGeometry objects with ranges of primitives from the original objects. It might be rather naive with respect to materials (my models uses simple colors; this code might not yet handle other textures correctly); and it may not work for primitives other than triangle strips.

The code is available in GitHub at https://github.com/Fyrestead/PartialGeometry

For completeness, the initial version is pasted below.

SCNGeometry addition:

```
//
//  SCNGeometry.swift
//
//  Created by Shon Frazier on 11/22/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Fyrestead, LLC. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import SceneKit

let allSemantics = [
    SCNGeometrySourceSemanticVertex,
    SCNGeometrySourceSemanticNormal,
    SCNGeometrySourceSemanticColor,
    SCNGeometrySourceSemanticTexcoord,
    SCNGeometrySourceSemanticVertexCrease,
    SCNGeometrySourceSemanticEdgeCrease,
    SCNGeometrySourceSemanticBoneWeights,
    SCNGeometrySourceSemanticBoneIndices
]


extension SCNGeometry {

    func geometryForRangeOfPrimitives(range: NSRange) -> SCNGeometry? {

        var primitiveType: SCNGeometryPrimitiveType

        var allElements: [SCNGeometryElement] = [SCNGeometryElement]()

        for i in 0..<self.geometryElementCount {
            let element = self.geometryElementAtIndex(i)
            if element == nil {
                continue
            }

            var newElement = element!.geometryElementForRangeOfPrimitives(range)

            if newElement != nil {
                allElements += [newElement!]
            }
        }


        var allSources: [SCNGeometrySource] = [SCNGeometrySource]()

        for semantic in allSemantics {
            var sources = self.geometrySourcesForSemantic(semantic)
            if sources == nil {
                continue
            }

            for source in sources! as [SCNGeometrySource] {
                var range: NSRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: 5)

                let newSource = source.geometrySourceForRangeOfPrimitives(range, primitiveType: SCNGeometryPrimitiveType.TriangleStrip)

                allSources += [newSource!]
            }
        }


        var newGeometry = SCNGeometry(sources: allSources, elements: allElements)
        newGeometry.materials = materials

        return newGeometry
    }
}
```

SCNGeometryElement addition:

```
//
//  SCNGeometryElement.swift
//
//  Created by Shon Frazier on 11/23/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Fyrestead, LLC. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import SceneKit

extension SCNGeometryElement {

    func geometryElementForRangeOfPrimitives(range: NSRange) -> SCNGeometryElement? {

        if data == nil {
            return nil
        }

        let newCount = range.length
        let newLocation = range.location * bytesPerIndex
        let newLength = range.length * bytesPerIndex
        let newRange = NSRange(location: newLocation, length: newLength)
        let newData = data!.subdataWithRange(newRange)

        let newElement = SCNGeometryElement(
            data: newData,
            primitiveType: primitiveType,
            primitiveCount: newCount,
            bytesPerIndex: bytesPerIndex
        )

        return newElement
    }

}
```

SCNGeometrySource addition:

```
//
//  SCNGeometrySource.swift
//
//  Created by Shon Frazier on 11/23/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Fyrestead, LLC. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import SceneKit

extension SCNGeometrySource {

    /* Preserves use of existing data buffer by changing only the offset */
    func geometrySourceForRangeOfVectors(range: NSRange) -> SCNGeometrySource? {

        if data == nil {
            return nil
        }

        let newOffset = dataOffset + range.location * (dataStride + bytesPerComponent * componentsPerVector)

        return SCNGeometrySource(
            data: data!,
            semantic: semantic,
            vectorCount: range.length,
            floatComponents: floatComponents,
            componentsPerVector: componentsPerVector,
            bytesPerComponent: bytesPerComponent,
            dataOffset: newOffset,
            dataStride: dataStride)
    }

    func geometrySourceForRangeOfPrimitives(range: NSRange, primitiveType: SCNGeometryPrimitiveType) -> SCNGeometrySource? {

        var newGSource: SCNGeometrySource?

        switch primitiveType {
        case .TriangleStrip, .Point:
            newGSource = geometrySourceForRangeOfVectors(range)

        case .Triangles:
            let newRange = NSRange(location: range.location * 3, length: range.length * 3)
            newGSource = geometrySourceForRangeOfVectors(newRange)

        case .Line:
            let newRange = NSRange(location: range.location * 2, length: range.length * 2)
            newGSource = geometrySourceForRangeOfVectors(newRange)
        }

        return newGSource
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

SceneKit does not offer tools to inspect the topology of your mesh and detect gaps. If your original model does not have these gaps then should try to find the issue in your STEP to DAE converter.

There is no convenience method to draw only some elements of your geometry. Creating a new geometry with just the elements you're interested in in fairly easy. If you want something quick and dirty you can also write a `SCNProgram` that does nothing in the vertex shader and discards the fragment in the fragment shader. The create an array of materials according to your needs and set it to the geometry.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's the STEP file that specifies the geometry incorrectly. I don't know if it's intentional (perhaps a way to encourage people to purchase the manufacturer's simulation software? I don't know ...) or if the human doing the export just made a mistake. At any rate, I think I've since decided simply "hiding" is not my intention. I need to serialize the selected geometry.